# How do I print a formview page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to create a routine to print pages with a formview table.  I have a routine for printing gridview, are they essentially the same?  Can this be modified to work with formview by changing GridView1 to FormView1?  This will work only when formview is in the readonly mode.  VB is the language preference.  Any help will be greatly appreciated by this newbie.

```
Protected Sub Print_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    GridView1.AllowPaging = False
    GridView1.DataBind()
    GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = True
    GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
    GridView1.Attributes("style") = "border-collapse:separate"
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If row.RowIndex Mod 30 = 0 AndAlso row.RowIndex <> 0 Then
            row.Attributes("style") = "page-break-after:always;"
        End If
    Next
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw)
    Dim gridHTML As String = sw.ToString().Replace("""", "'").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "")
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
    sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){")
    sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0")
    sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');")
    sb.Append("printWin.document.write(""")
    Dim style As String = "<style type = 'text/css'>thead {display:table-header-group;} tfoot{display:table-footer-group;}</style>"
    sb.Append(style & gridHTML)
    sb.Append(""");")
    sb.Append("printWin.document.close();")
    sb.Append("printWin.focus();")
    sb.Append("printWin.print();")
    sb.Append("printWin.close();")
    sb.Append("};")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "GridPrint", sb.ToString())
    GridView1.AllowPaging = True
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I trimmed/changed the above to the following below but get a "System.Web.HttpException: Control 'FormView1' of type 'FormView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server." error message and am now totally lost as to how to fix it.  The error comes from the line "FormView1.RenderControl(hw)"

```
Protected Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    FormView1.AllowPaging = False
    FormView1.DataBind()
    FormView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
    FormView1.Attributes("style") = "border-collapse:separate"
    Dim sw As New StringWriter()
    Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
    FormView1.RenderControl(hw)
    Dim gridHTML As String = sw.ToString().Replace("""", "'").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "")
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
    sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){")
    sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0")
    sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');")
    sb.Append("printWin.document.write(""")
    Dim style As String = "<style type = 'text/css'>thead {display:table-header-group;} tfoot{display:table-footer-group;}</style>"
    sb.Append(style & gridHTML)
    sb.Append(""");")
    sb.Append("printWin.document.close();")
    sb.Append("printWin.focus();")
    sb.Append("printWin.print();")
    sb.Append("printWin.close();")
    sb.Append("};")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "GridPrint", sb.ToString())
    FormView1.AllowPaging = True
    FormView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`, `GridView1.DataBind`? are you sure this is WPF code? this look like an ASP.net code.

Comment: As FormView Table built with Template structure you cann't perform "page-break-after:always" logic that you perform here for every 30 rows. I don't know your exact requirement but for your FormView based table structure case, I suggest you to go from f/e JavaScript with the same that you constructed in the above routine, only additional thing you have to handle is page-break-after:always for every 30 rows with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to do two things.
1. I needed to add a routine to my vb code behind:

```
Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control As Control)
    ' Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET     server control at run time.
End Sub
```

2. I needed to add the following to the aspx code header:

EnableEventValidation = "false"

All is working well now and I have added a similar "Export to Excel" function.